# Using docker environment -e variable in supervisor

Tags: python, docker, environment-variables, supervisord

I've been trying to pass in an environment variable to a Docker container via the `-e` option. The variable is meant to be used in a supervisor script within the container. Unfortunately, the variable does not get resolved (i.e. they stay for instance`$INSTANCENAME`). I tried `${var}` and `"${var}"`, but this didn't help either. Is there anything I can do or is this just not possible?

The docker run command:

```
sudo docker run -d -e "INSTANCENAME=instance-1" -e "FOO=2" -v /var/app/tmp:/var/app/tmp -t myrepos/app:tag
```

and the supervisor file:

```
[program:app]
command=python test.py --param1=$FOO
stderr_logfile=/var/app/log/$INSTANCENAME.log
directory=/var/app
autostart=true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable is being passed to your container, but supervisor doesn't let use environment variables like this inside the configuration files.

You should review the [supervisor documentation](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html), and specifically the parts about string expressions. For example, for the `command` option:

> Note that the value of `command` may include Python string expressions, e.g. `/path/to/programname --port=80%(process_num)02d` might expand to `/path/to/programname --port=8000` at runtime.
>
> String expressions are evaluated against a dictionary containing the keys `group_name`, `host_node_name`, `process_num`, `program_name`, here (the directory of the supervisord config file), and all supervisord’s environment variables prefixed with `ENV_`.