# Pass environment variable from docker to supervisord

Tags: docker, supervisord

I pass two env variables with docker run:

```
docker run -d --name foobar -e STAGE=testing -e STAGE_URL=http://...
```

and the dockerfile kicks of supervisor which launches a couple of processes:

```
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "--configuration", "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf"]
```

In the `supervisord.conf` I try to read the variables:

```
[program:build]
priority=1
autorestart=false
directory=/app/foobar
command=grunt build --force --stage ${STAGE} --stage-url ${STAGE_URL}
```

I tried also with

```
$STAGE
```

and

```
%(STAGE)s
```

But STAGE is never treated as a variable. It is never replaced with the actual content. Instead it is treated as a simple string. This results in:

```
--stage STAGE --stage-url STAGE_URL
```

instead of

```
--stage testing --stage-url http://...
```

Is this even possible what I am doing? Supervisor docs are not clear about this topic. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31069834/using-docker-environment-e-variable-in-supervisor

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `%(ENV_STAGE)s`.

The [docs](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html) seem to suggest that's the way to go.